Python: Trying to create a Parse & Sum Function to call later
As the title states, I'm trying to create (def) a function wherein I import re and then parse through a string (using Regular Expressions) to add the numbers up at the end in a list. I know the code works outside of the function I am trying to save. I've just never created a function this complex so I'm unsure of indentation usage or if it's possible.
Edit: After indenting my 'print' statement, the function does work. However it prints out all 87 lines and the sum per line. I had it on the outside of the loop so that it would only show one line. I just want it to show the last line (total sum and how many lines were counted). Before while working on this outside of the function I attempted to splice but that didn't work. I have also only been working with Python for maybe 5 days so please be gentle lol. I often go back and review material or google for an answer I can understand.
#create function to import the re lib and then parse through "fhand" after the file is opened by calling this function.

def Ptfs():
    import re
    count = 0
    total = list()
    for line in fhand:
        numbers = re.findall('[0-9]+' ,line) 
        for number in numbers :
            num = int(number)
            total.append(num)
            count = count + 1
print(sum(total), "There were", count,  "lines that were summed.")

fhand = open("file_name", 'r')
Ptfs() 


Your print call is outside of the function, so that won't work.  But a more normal way to do this would be to pass the file name, or the open file handle, to your function as an argument, and for the function to return the result, leaving it to the caller to print it.  Also, you didn't close fhand.  It will be closed when the function exits, but it's cleaner to explicitly close it.

Would that be



Ptfs(fhand=open("file_name", 'r')
I don't quite understand what you mean when you say for the function to return the result, leaving it to the caller to print it. If I understand the syntax, my above code in this comment does pass fhand through to my function.. but I"m unsure of the syntax to have my function just return the result without print
and I'm not sure how to close the fhand. I know there's proper memory usage to use when working with files but I don't exactly know that syntax yet. Sorry for the edit, pressed enter lol




You only need to indent the print statement once, not within the for loop

THAT WORKED. Thanks! Sorry for the noob question! I'm just trying to build my own functions with what I"m taught so I can call on them later and edit them as I learn more :)

@NaethanPeters What I mean is that normally a function like that would return the result, as in return sum(total), count, rather than printing it.  That way it could serve a more general purpose.

There's a few improvements you can make - hopefully this a) works and b) does the same thing you were doing...
import re  # don't import modules inside functions

def Ptfs(filename):  # pass filename into function
    
    count = 0
    total = 0  # calculate total as we go

    with open(filename) as fhand:  # use with so file gets closed automatically
        for line in fhand:
            numbers = re.findall('[0-9]+' ,line) 
            for number in numbers :
                total += int(number)
            count += 1 # shorthand for count = count + 1
    return count, total

# pass filename into function and return count and total
count, total = Ptfs("file_name") 
# use f-strings to format output
print(f"{total} There were {count} lines that were summed.")



Note: you may not want to return count/total in which case you could move the print into the loop
